# Spring Cache Abstraction with multi-value queries

Tags: java, spring, caching

Does Spring Cache abstraction support multi-value queries?

Instead of:

@Cacheable("books")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}

Imagine a query that goes like this:

@Cacheable("books")
public List< Book > findBook(List< ISBN > isbns) {...}

Is this supported? Will it individually cache each book returned in the collection?

Thanks!

Comment: See a related post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co) to which I provided 1 possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Cache stores whole result under single cache key, so it is not possible to store individually each object returned in the collection. In case of caching result of a JPA Query you may use query cache. In other cases if memcached is an option for you, you can try [Simple Spring Memcached](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/) and ReadThroughMultiCache annotation. It will store each element of the collection individually under dedicated cache key.

Answer (score 2):

The **query cache** can indeed cache a list of results per query input. Be aware thought, that only the IDs of the returned entities will be saved in the query cache. You have to have the **entity cache** enabled separately for the returned entity type itself, if you want the properties to be cached too.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. Here's a link to my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992530/2891027

TL:DR

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "test", key = "#p0")
public List<String> getTestFunction(List<String> someIds) {
```

My example is with String and not custom object.

Hope it helps at least a bit :)